# How to completely reset Cypress state between tests

Tags: cypress

My question is: **how can I completely reset Cypress state between tests?**

I'm working on a legacy codebase that has hundreds of Cypress tests which pass/fail depending on the order in which they happen to be run. For example, the file I'm working on  right now has 3 tests: A, B, and C:

- If each test is run individually, then each test will pass
- If each test is run consecutively, then

  - If the test order is A, B, C, then test C will fail
  - If the test order is B, A, C, then all tests will pass

If only I was able to tell Cypress to reset state between tests, I wouldn't have this problem. I know that Cypress is technically able to do this, because I can clickety-click Cypress to run tests individually, in which case they do pass. But for some reason Cypress doesn't seem to offer me a programmatic ability to run these tests independently of each other.

The standard answer to this type of question is doing stuff inside `before` blocks to reset state. This code already exists in the legacy codebase. That reset code is able to successfully reset backend state, but it is not successful in resetting client state inside the browser where Cypress runs. At least the following are not reset correctly between tests:

- I can see that the previously rendered view remains visible in the browser window between tests and I think it runs some JS code that interferes on stuff
- I can see that cookies are not cleared between tests

I tried to fix these issues by adding stuff to the `reset` function. I made it clear cookies and I made it navigate to another page. I fully expected this to resolve the issues. I was surprised to find out that clearing cookies inside the `before` block causes test B to break (previously: A passes -> B passes -> C fails. now: A passes -> B fails -> C passes). This does not make sense to me, because if I run test B individually (starting from no cookies at all), then it passes! After I added some `wait` calls to investigate, I found out that some cookies are being set before the `before` block is activated. This, again, does not make sense to me, because I can't figure out which part of Cypress is causing this legacy codebase to add these cookies, and why. The cookies don't even seem to come directly from this system, but rather, it's loading a bunch of JS files from other services, and those files seem to be setting the cookies. Again, it does not make sense to me why this happens before Cypress runs the `before` block.

There should be a way to completely reset Cypress state between tests, but how?

Comment: See the [Test Isolation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation) page, this should be automatic if you have the default value `true`. Are you using an earlier version of Cypress? Try upgrading to v12.6.0.

Comment: I have read the Test Isolation page, and based on what I see right now, Cypress does not appear to work as described on that page. I can not find the term "testIsolation" anywhere in this codebase, so presumably it is set to default value "true" and Cypress should be isolating tests, but it is not doing so. I am on v9 of Cypress and I am unable to ugrade to v12 without doing performing multiple weeks of work upgrading dependencies and troubleshooting issues.

Comment: That's a pity. I think you should bite the bullet and upgrade, otherwise "weeks of work" will be "months of failures".